# Restore Global Shortcuts → Activate Application Launcher Widget

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde-plasma-5

I just installed [hardinfo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125062/how-can-i-find-which-desktop-enviroment-i-am-using#comment1764505_281459)

**I lost the Meta Default Shortcut**. I dont now why. I installed AutoKey, OBS, CopyQ, Wine, AutoHotKey.
And i changed the Task Menaager Size.

System specification:

KDE neon User Edition 5.19
KDE Desktop

Default Shortcut for the
[Application Launcher](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma_application_launchers)
is the **Meta** Key.

At

System Settings → Shortcuts → Global Shortcuts → Plasma → Activate Application Launcher Widget.

i could set Shortcuts like Meta + F1 or Meta + y but nut to the default. just Meta.

Any Idea?

Maybe set shortcut Meta in AutoKey?
This not working to start `keyboard.send_key("<alt>+<shift>")` Krunner

Comment: this helps me a bit: it set meta to another usefule function: ```kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta "org.kde.kglobalaccel,/component/krunner_desktop,org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component,invokeShortcut,_launch"
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure``` found here: [KDE ... Meta_Key](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Tips#Windows.2FMeta_Key)

Comment: I had to set any shortcut (really, any) in right-click on the start menu/KDE icon, "Configure Application Launcher...", Keyboard Shortcuts. For me it was `Alt+²` because the `Alt+F1` which everyone talks about didn't work for me: the setting was never applied. If I applied, selected the "General" tab and re-select "Keyboard Shortcuts", it was back to unassigned.